# How to remove all non alphanumeric chars from a String without remove @ symbols

Tags: java, regex

currently using this regex: `s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");` however it removes values I need such as `@ . , !` how can I include these in my regex so they do not get replaced with empty strings.

Cheers

Comment: so include them in your character class if you need them..`[^a-zA-Z0-9@.,!]`

Answer (score 4):

Just add them to the regex. Note that `.` is a special character, so you'd have to escape it:

```
String newString = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9!@\\.,]", "");
```

Comment: @4castle Technically wrong, since you don't *have* to. but it doesn't hurt. Regex will work with or without the escape.

Comment: @chris85 See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#classes. Also, `regex101` is not Java. `[t[esa]` causes `PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 6`

Comment: I'm deleting previous comments cause I think getting off topic from the answer. I think the `.` doesn't need to be escaped in the character class unless that is special for JAVA. @Andreas oh, thanks for that link.